# zend update statement ,not updating database row

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

here is my code

```
$id = $this->user->id;
$data['last_cust_code']     = $a_Search['custcode'];
$data['last_paid_filter']   = $a_Search['paid'];
$data['last_unpd_filter']   = $a_Search['unpaid'];
$data['last_group_field']   = $a_Search['grouping'];
$data['last_session_code']  = $a_Search['session'];
$out = $objDb->update('tblusrusers', $data,array("id = ?"=>$id));
```

profiler output

```
UPDATE `tblusrusers` SET `last_cust_code` = ?, `last_paid_filter` = ?, `last_unpd_filter` = ?, `last_group_field` = ?, `last_session_code` = ? WHERE (id = '70')

Array
(
    [1] => TESTAAA
    [2] => N
    [3] => N
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 19993E
)
```

when i update directly through mysql client its updating properly.

IMPORTANT:When i select the output through a query i am able to see the update ,but not in through phpmyadmin.does it has something to do with commit statements ,i mean is my autocommit is false?for some other queries am using transactions will it effect my above update query?please help

Comment: How transactions configured in your database? Do you try $objDb-> commit(); after finishing query?

Comment: Everything looks correct. How are you connecting to your database? Which adapter are you using? Does your $data array properties match your database column names exactly? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Electronick i have auto commit enable in db .

Comment: @RockyFord no errors columns and data are matching

Comment: that just leaves your adapter or your db setup.

Comment: @RockyFord i use zend transaction for some queries ,is that the reason for the issue

Comment: shouldn't, unless you have some unusual settings in your database or database adapter related to transactions. How are you accomplishing profiling?

Comment: print $objDb->getProfiler()->getLastQueryProfile()->getQuery();
   print_r($objDb->getProfiler()->getLastQueryProfile()->getQueryParams());
$objDb->getProfiler()->setEnabled(false);

Comment: I nothin' more sorry. Maybe check your Mysql for a file with the ext of .err for possible errors that aren't making it to the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is someone in my production team just put an `$objDb->beginTransaction()`
but did not commit using `$objDb->commit()` which resulted in mysql database auto commit to false(bcoz the began transaction statement set autocommit to false) therefore all the other queries where not working since commit was not happening .

Answer (score 0):

I never used Zend but I think your data array should be as

```
$data = array('last_cust_code' => $a_Search['custcode'],
             'last_paid_filter' => $a_Search['paid'],
             'last_unpd_filter' => $a_Search['unpaid'],
             'last_group_field' => $a_Search['grouping'],
             'last_session_code' => $a_Search['session'] );
```

Comment: query is build properly u can check the profiler o/p ,that i ahve shown .but it has somthing to do with database config i think